# Binary search tree implementation (with Node class)

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search

I have implemented the Binary Search Tree in Java and would love to get reviews. I would like to have some comments on multi thread implantation.

***Note: Corrected Code is in the Answers***

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.binarytree;

import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.ITree;
import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.ITreeNode;
import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.DFTreeTraverser;

@SuppressWarnings ( {"rawtypes", "unchecked"} )
public class BinaryTree implements ITree {

  private ITreeNode    root;
  public DFTreeTraverser treeTraverser = new DFTreeTraverser(root);

  @Override
  public void insert( Comparable data ) {
    root = insert(data, root);
  }

  @Override
  public void remove( Comparable data ) {
    if ( isEmpty() )
      System.out.println("Tree Empty");
    else if ( find(data) == null )
      System.out.println("Sorry " + data + " is not present");
    else {
      root = remove(data, root);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void removeMin() {
    ITreeNode minimumNode = findMin(root);
    Comparable data = minimumNode.getData();
    remove(data);
  }

  @Override
  public Comparable find( Comparable data ) {
    ITreeNode dataNode = find(data, root);
    return (dataNode != null) ? dataNode.getData() : null;
  }

  @Override
  public Comparable findMin() {
    ITreeNode minimumNode = findMin(root);
    return minimumNode.getData();
  }

  @Override
  public Comparable findMax() {
    ITreeNode maximumNode = findMax(root);
    return maximumNode.getData();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null ? true : false;
  }

  @Override
  public void makeEmpty() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  protected ITreeNode findMax( ITreeNode node ) {
    while (node.hasRightNode()) {
      node = node.getRightNode();
    }
    return node;
  }

  protected ITreeNode findMin( ITreeNode node ) {
    while (node.hasLeftNode()) {
      node = node.getLeftNode();
    }
    return node;
  }

  protected ITreeNode find( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    if ( node == null ) return null;
    if ( node.getData().compareTo(data) == 0 ) return node;
    if ( node.getData().compareTo(data) < 0 ) return find(data, node.getRightNode());
    return find(data, node.getLeftNode());
  }

  protected ITreeNode insert( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    ITreeNode n;
    if ( node == null ) {
      node = new BinaryTreeNode(data);
    } else if ( data.compareTo(node.getData()) < 0 ) {
      n = insert(data, node.getLeftNode());
      node.setLeftNode(n);
    } else if ( data.compareTo(node.getData()) > 0 ) {
      n = insert(data, node.getRightNode());
      node.setRightNode(n);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Data already in the Tree.");
    }
    return node;
  }

  protected ITreeNode remove( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    ITreeNode maxInLeftTree, newLeftChild, n;
    if ( node == null ) {
      return null;
    }
    if ( node.getData() == data ) {
      ITreeNode leftChild = node.getLeftNode();
      ITreeNode rightChild = node.getRightNode();
      if ( leftChild == null && rightChild == null ) // BOTH of the Child are null and Value
                                                     // matched.
        return null;
      else if ( leftChild == null ) {
        return rightChild;
      } else if ( rightChild == null ) {
        return leftChild;
      } else {
        maxInLeftTree = findMax(leftChild);
        Comparable value = maxInLeftTree.getData();
        newLeftChild = remove(value, leftChild);
        node.setData(value);
        node.setLeftNode(newLeftChild);
        return node;
      }
    }
    if ( data.compareTo(node.getData()) < 0 ) {
      n = remove(data, node.getLeftNode());
      node.setLeftNode(n);
    } else {
      n = remove(data, node.getRightNode());
      node.setRightNode(n);
    }
    return node;
  }

  @Override
  public DFTreeTraverser getTraverser() {
    treeTraverser.setRoot(root);
    return treeTraverser;
  }


  class BinaryTreeNode implements ITreeNode {

    ITreeNode  leftNode  = null;
    ITreeNode  rightNode = null;
    Comparable data      = null;

    public void setLeftNode( ITreeNode leftNode ) {
      this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }

    public void setRightNode( ITreeNode rightNode ) {
      this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }

    @Override
    public ITreeNode getLeftNode() {
      return this.leftNode;
    }

    @Override
    public ITreeNode getRightNode() {
      return this.rightNode;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable getData() {
      return this.data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasLeftNode() {
      return (this.leftNode != null) ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasRightNode() {
      return (this.rightNode != null) ? true : false;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode( Comparable data ) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.data.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void setData( Comparable data ) {
      this.data = data;
    }
  }


  @Override
  public int size() {
    return size(root);
  }

  public int size(ITreeNode node) {

    int leftSize = 0,rightSize =0;

    if(node==null)
      return 0;

    if(node.hasLeftNode())
      leftSize = size(node.getLeftNode());

    if(node.hasRightNode())
      rightSize = size(node.getRightNode());

    return leftSize+rightSize+1;
  }

  @Override
  public ITreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
  }



}
```

Comment: I've opted to rollback the question, see: [What should I *not* do when someone answers my question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Can I write changed code as answer? @h.j.k.

Comment: There's a "Posting a self-answer." section in the page I linked to, and generally nothing is stopping you from doing so. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

**Generics**

Your `Comparable` is missing it. And I suppose your custom classes are all missing it too. That explains why you are `@Supress`-ing `"unchecked"` warnings. I'm not sure if the root cause is because you are retro-fitting some older < Java 1.5 implementations or not, but for type safety **please use generics**. :)

Some other pointers:

```
@Override
public void insert( Comparable data ) {
  root = insert(data, root);
}
```

You probably want to update your `treeTraverser` here when you (potentially) re-assign your `root`.

---

```
@Override
public void remove( Comparable data ) {
    if ( isEmpty() )
      System.out.println("Tree Empty");
    else if ( find(data) == null )
      System.out.println("Sorry " + data + " is not present");
    else {
      root = remove(data, root);
    }
}
```

1. Inconsistent use of braces here, I'll suggest using it throughout.
2. Using `System.out` to do logging is a poor choice here, as the logging feature should be abstracted away to a logging framework. With that, you can optionally turn on/off messages on a per-level basis (e.g. `DEBUG` for development, but `WARN` for production), or even change the formatting.

---

```
@Override
public void removeMin() {
  ITreeNode minimumNode = findMin(root);
  Comparable data = minimumNode.getData();
  remove(data);
}

@Override
public Comparable findMin() {
    ITreeNode minimumNode = findMin(root);
    return minimumNode.getData();
}
```

Duplicated code. You can simply `return findMin(root).getData();` from `findMin()`. Ditto for `findMax()`.

---

```
protected ITreeNode findMax( ITreeNode node ) {
    while (node.hasRightNode()) {
      node = node.getRightNode();
    }
    return node;
}
```

Even though this is a very short method, I personally don't favor reassigning method arguments as it may get confusing as to what is being modified/assigned in the future, or for other longer methods. Ditto for `findMin(ITreeNode)`. An alternative for writing the loop above may be:

```
protected ITreeNode findMax( ITreeNode node ) {
    for (ITreeNode current = node; current.hasRightNode(); 
            current = current.getRightNode()) {
        // empty
    }
    return current;
}
```

---

```
protected ITreeNode find( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    if ( node == null ) return null;
    if ( node.getData().compareTo(data) == 0 ) return node;
    if ( node.getData().compareTo(data) < 0 ) return find(data, node.getRightNode());
    return find(data, node.getLeftNode());
}
```

I'll suggest saving `node.getData().compareTo(data)` to a temporary variable and then operate on that:

```
protected ITreeNode find( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    if ( node == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    int result = node.getData().compareTo(data);
    return result == 0 ? node : 
            find(data, result < 0 ? node.getRightNode() : node.getLeftNode());
}
```

---

```
protected ITreeNode insert( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    ITreeNode n;
    if ( node == null ) {
      node = new BinaryTreeNode(data);
    } else if ( data.compareTo(node.getData()) < 0 ) {
      n = insert(data, node.getLeftNode());
      node.setLeftNode(n);
    } else if ( data.compareTo(node.getData()) > 0 ) {
      n = insert(data, node.getRightNode());
      node.setRightNode(n);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Data already in the Tree.");
    }
    return node;
}
```

1. You don't need the `n` temporary variable.
2. However, similar to the previous point, you may consider having a temporary variable to store the results of doing the `compareTo()`.
3. Do you really want to throw an `Exception` for existing data? How about simply returning the `Node` unmodified?

Putting the suggestions together:

```
protected ITreeNode insert( Comparable data, ITreeNode node ) {
    if ( node == null ) {
        return new BinaryTreeNode(data);
    }
    int result = data.compareTo(node.getData());
    if ( result < 0 ) {
        node.setLeftNode(insert(data, node.getLeftNode()));
    } else if ( result > 0 ) {
        node.setRightNode(insert(data, node.getRightNode()));
    } else {
        // throw new RuntimeException("Data already in the Tree."); ?
    }
    return node;
}
```

---

`remove()` is kind of long to copy here so I'll just mention this: You have one inconsistent usage of braces.

---

```
@Override
public boolean hasLeftNode() {
    return (this.leftNode != null) ? true : false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasRightNode() {
    return (this.rightNode != null) ? true : false;
}
```

You don't need the ternary operator here, just do `return leftNode != null` or `return rightNode != null` respectively.

---

```
public int size(ITreeNode node) {

    int leftSize = 0,rightSize =0;

    if(node==null)
        return 0;

    if(node.hasLeftNode())
        leftSize = size(node.getLeftNode());

    if(node.hasRightNode())
        rightSize = size(node.getRightNode());

    return leftSize+rightSize+1;
}
```

You have pretty consistent and decent whitespacing... until here. You can probably shorten your code as such:

```
public int size(ITreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return size(node.getLeftNode()) + size(node.getRightNode()) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for your feedback. Will check my code for these and then will ask you questions.

Comment: I have Implemented the changes on the Code. Traverser root is already being changed in getTranverser Function.   @Override
  public DFTreeTraverser<T> getTraverser() {
    treeTraverser.setRoot(root);
    return treeTraverser;
  }

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I could add is that the main interest of a binary search tree resides in the log(n) height.
Without some re-balancing mechanism, in worst case, the tree will behave like a list.  You may be interested in taking a look to AVL (they always have an optimal depth), Red-Black, ...

Comment: True. Well I have implemented self balancing binary tree in another class. Will share that too for the code review. This was my first tree implementation:)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the corrected code of above Question.
Will update this if I get more answers.

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.binarytree;

import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.ITree;
import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.ITreeNode;
import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.tree.DFTreeTraverser;

public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ITree<T> {

  private ITreeNode<T>      root;
  public DFTreeTraverser<T> treeTraverser = new DFTreeTraverser<T>(root);

  @Override
  public void insert( T data ) {
    root = insert(data, root);
  }

  @Override
  public void remove( T data ) {
    if ( isEmpty() )
      System.out.println("Tree Empty");
    else if ( find(data) == null )
      System.out.println("Sorry " + data + " is not present");
    else {
      root = remove(data, root);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void removeMin() {
    ITreeNode<T> minimumNode = findMin(root);
    T data = minimumNode.getData();
    remove(data);
  }

  @Override
  public T find( T data ) {
    ITreeNode<T> dataNode = find(data, root);
    return (dataNode != null) ? dataNode.getData() : null;
  }

  @Override
  public T findMin() {
    return findMin(root).getData();
  }

  @Override
  public T findMax() {
    return findMax(root).getData();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null ? true : false;
  }

  @Override
  public void makeEmpty() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  protected ITreeNode<T> findMax( ITreeNode<T> node ) {
    ITreeNode<T> current = node;
    while (current.hasRightNode()) {
      current = current.getRightNode();
    }
    return current;
  }

  protected ITreeNode<T> findMin( ITreeNode<T> node ) {
    ITreeNode<T> current = node;
    while (current.hasLeftNode()) {
      current = current.getLeftNode();
    }
    return current;
  }

  protected ITreeNode<T> find( T data, ITreeNode<T> node ) {
    if ( node == null ) return null;
    int result = node.getData().compareTo(data);
    return result == 0 ? node : find(data, result < 0 ? node.getRightNode() : node.getLeftNode());
  }

  protected ITreeNode<T> insert( T data, ITreeNode<T> node ) {
    ITreeNode<T> n;
    if ( node == null ) {
      node = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(data);
      return node;
    }
    int result = data.compareTo(node.getData());
    if ( result < 0 ) {
      n = insert(data, node.getLeftNode());
      node.setLeftNode(n);
    } else if ( result > 0 ) {
      n = insert(data, node.getRightNode());
      node.setRightNode(n);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Data already in the Tree.");
    }
    return node;
  }

  protected ITreeNode<T> remove( T data, ITreeNode<T> node ) {
    ITreeNode<T> maxInLeftTree, newLeftChild, n;
    if ( node == null ) {
      return null;
    }
    if ( node.getData() == data ) {
      ITreeNode<T> leftChild = node.getLeftNode();
      ITreeNode<T> rightChild = node.getRightNode();
      if ( leftChild == null && rightChild == null ) // BOTH of the Child are null and Value
                                                     // matched.
        return null;
      else if ( leftChild == null ) {
        return rightChild;
      } else if ( rightChild == null ) {
        return leftChild;
      } else {
        maxInLeftTree = findMax(leftChild);
        T value = maxInLeftTree.getData();
        newLeftChild = remove(value, leftChild);
        node.setData(value);
        node.setLeftNode(newLeftChild);
        return node;
      }
    }
    if ( data.compareTo(node.getData()) < 0 ) {
      n = remove(data, node.getLeftNode());
      node.setLeftNode(n);
    } else {
      n = remove(data, node.getRightNode());
      node.setRightNode(n);
    }
    return node;
  }

  @Override
  public DFTreeTraverser<T> getTraverser() {
    treeTraverser.setRoot(root);
    return treeTraverser;
  }


  class BinaryTreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ITreeNode<E> {

    ITreeNode<E> leftNode  = null;
    ITreeNode<E> rightNode = null;
    E            data      = null;

    public void setLeftNode( ITreeNode<E> leftNode ) {
      this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }

    public void setRightNode( ITreeNode<E> rightNode ) {
      this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }

    @Override
    public ITreeNode<E> getLeftNode() {
      return this.leftNode;
    }

    @Override
    public ITreeNode<E> getRightNode() {
      return this.rightNode;
    }

    @Override
    public E getData() {
      return this.data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasLeftNode() {
      return this.leftNode != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasRightNode() {
      return this.rightNode != null;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode( E data ) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.data.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void setData( E data ) {
      this.data = data;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return size(root);
  }

  public int size( ITreeNode<T> node ) {
    if ( node == null ) return 0;
    return size(node.getLeftNode()) + size(node.getRightNode()) + 1;
  }

  @Override
  public ITreeNode<T> getRoot() {
    return root;
  }
}
```